# In plesk server Codeigniter Mail Function not working with gmail on server side but good in localhost?

Tags: codeigniter, email, smtp, gmail, plesk

Everything going great on Codeigniter localhost but on particuler Plesk Linux Server I get the different type of error as per changing the port number and protocols. I'm really hanging on this problem, also read the documentation of Plesk but I didn't understand. Hope on StackOverflow someone gives a solution.

I tried most of the all port and protocols to get the result but not succeded. Used code

```
function sendMail()
{
  $this->load->library('email');
  // ini_set('SMTP', "smtp.rediffmailpro.com");
  // ini_set('smtp_port', "25");
  // ini_set('sendmail_from', "myemailid");
  // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
  // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $config = array(
      // for rediff mail setup
      // 'protocol' => 'smtp',
      // 'smtp_host' => 'smtp.rediffmailpro.com',
      // 'smtp_port' => 587,
      // 'smtp_user' => 'email.com',
      // 'smtp_pass' => 'pass',
      // 'mailtype' => 'html',
      // 'charset' => 'iso-8859-1', //'UTF-8'
      // 'wordwrap' => TRUE

      // for gmail setup
      'protocol' => 'smtp', //'mail', 'sendmail', 'tls' tried these but get different type of errors
      'smtp_host' => 'smtp.gmail.com', /*'smtp.googlemail.com',*/
      'smtp_port' => 587, //465
      'smtp_user' => 'user email',
      'smtp_pass' => 'user pass',
      //'smtp_crypto' => 'smtp',
      'mailtype' => 'html',
      'smtp_timeout' => 5,
      'charset' => 'utf-8',
      'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->from('email','AG'); // change it to yours 
    $this->email->to('your email');// change it to yours
    $this->email->subject('Test Mail');
    $this->email->message('Dont be pannic.');  
      $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
      if($this->email->send())
       {
        echo 'Email sent.';
       }
     else
      {
       show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
      }
}
```

At this condition I get this error

> Failed to authenticate password. Error: 534-5.7.14 Please log
>   534-5.7.14 in via your web browser and then try again. 534-5.7.14
>   Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754
>   k11sm2916535wmk.45 - gsmtp Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your
>   server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

But on given google url didn't get any idea about my problem or I didn't get it.

After changing

```
port 465,
smtp_hot "ssl://email.com",
```

Get this error

> Failed to authenticate password. Error: 534-5.7.14 Please log
>   534-5.7.14 in via your web browser and then try again. 534-5.7.14
>   Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754
>   y66sm2047426wmd.37 - gsmtp Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your
>   server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
>   I don't understand what am I doing wrong.

Want to successfully send mail. On Plesk server

Comment: Few things to check 
- Have u tried contacting your server administrator regarding sending smtp mail? Some server just block smtp mail. Ask them to allow smtp mail.
- Or, try sending mail without using smtp auth.

Comment: Yes, I do and they told me that your hosting provider is someone else. I don't understand this, I have Plesk server, all sites are hosted and they told me this. But finally using on PHPMailer I solve this problem but of course, this is an alternative. It's a service provider side problem because I tried every protocol and port to do this.